# Does not work _cgets. Identifier not found

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to compile the following code in visual studio 2019:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
int main() 
{
     char buffer[5];
    char* p;
    buffer[0] = 3;
    p = _cgets(buffer); // problem with _cgets
    printf("\ncgets read %d symbols: \"%s\"\n", buffer[1], p);
    printf("A pointer is returned %p, buffer[2] on %p\n", p, &buffer);

return 0;
}
```

But I see the following error:

```
main.cpp(11,9): error C3861: '_cgets': identifier not found
```

Comment: @AlanBirtles when i replace buffer [1], p with p, buffer [1] i get an error. because a pointer cannot be converted to decimal. Did I understand you correctly? and does buffer [1] store the code of the second entered character after the function ends?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I have five cells in memory. `buffer[0]` stores the maximum length of the string, in `buffer[1]` contains the number of elements to be read. after `buffer[2]` cells are actually the symbols that the user entered. and in the last cell `\0`

Comment: @AlanBirtles, when returned `str [1]` contains the number characters read. so, if you enter for example `"H"`, in `buffer[1]` stores the value 0, although logically it should be 1. or if you enter `"Hi"` or `"Hii"` or `"Hiii"` `buffer[1]` contains 105 characters instead of 2, 3, 4 respectively. Why?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i don't understand what is the minimum reproducible example you want. it is impossible to describe the problem in more detail. do you need a code? it is higher, do you need a problem? it's also higher what else? in addition, this characteristic is inherent in `_cgets`, but when I replace `gets_s `with `_cgets` it throws an error.
`Error (active) E0020 identifier "_cgets" is undefined`

Comment: `p = _cgets(buffer);`  here i have problem -> `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error (active) E0020 identifier "_cgets" is undefined` and `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C3861 '_cgets': identifier not found ConsoleApplication1` . compiler version is 19.29.30133.0. linked libraries: `#include <iostream>`
`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <math.h>`
`#include <conio.h>`
`#include <string>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[_cgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/cgets-cgetws?view=msvc-160) is no longer available, use [_cgets_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cgets-s-cgetws-s?view=msvc-160) instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    char buffer[5];
    size_t sizeRead;
    auto error = _cgets_s(buffer, &sizeRead);
    printf("\ncgets read %zu symbols: \"%s\"\n", sizeRead, buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Or the much simpler c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string buffer;
    std::getline(std::cin, buffer);
    std::cout << "read " << buffer.size() << " characters \"" << buffer << "\"\n";
}
```